# How to search for a node in a general tree

Tags: c++, tree, traversal

I am trying to search through a tree like the ones below:

[image]

but I am having trouble with the code to do so.I want to go through every node in the tree and if it is found i want it to return true. Please help

```
    bool search(int data)
    {
        return search(root, data);//call the recursive function
    }
    bool search(gennode *node, int data)
    {
        if(node == NULL)
        {
            return false; 
        }
        else if(node->item != data)
        {
            return search(node->firstchild, data);
        }
        else if(node->firstchild == NULL )
        {
            return search(node->siblinglist, data);
        }
        else if(node->siblinglist-> item!= data)
        {
            return search(node->siblinglist, data);
        }
        else if(node -> siblinglist == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else 
        return true;
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: [Depth first search or Breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

Comment: your class `gennode` seems to be a pretty weird implementation of a node. Can you please include it, so we know how it works?